# how to operate static?

Tags: java, default, operator-keyword, static-members

Whenever we use static, we need not create a reference variable of a class. We can directly access class with the help of `<class_name>`

But when we write the following code:

```
class Abc
{
    static void show()
    {
        System.out.println("Hey I am static");
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Abc.show();            //1
        new Abc().show();      //2
    }
}
```

How does both the lines 1 & 2 work. what is the significance of

```
new Abc().show();
```

Comment: Please indent your code. ;)

Comment: Static methods are associated with the *class*, not an instance. The "proper" way of invoking the method would be to call it with the class name (ie Abc.show()). The most obvious reason to show this is if you are browsing code and see an instance call a method, you are going to assume that method will be associated with the instance, not the class. Having an instance call a static method can be misleading/confusing to someone glancing at your code.

Comment: Calling static method on an instance will result in a warning, though it will also just call the static method on the class. Thre reason it compiles is simply because the class of and instance is given anyway, however it is a bad and pointless practice.

Comment: Please, consider an up vote if my answer was to the point. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an instance (although it works) is the *wrong* way of invoking a `static` method (or access static fields) *because static denotes its **a member of the class/type*** and not the instance.

The compiler would therefore replace the instance with the `Class` type (due to static binding). In other words, **at runtime**, `ABC.show()` gets executed instead of `new ABC().show()`.

However, your source code would still look confusing. Hence, it's considered a bad practice and would even result in warnings from IDEs like Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Since your ABC class did'nt override the default constructor.

It's equivalent to :

```
class Abc{
    public Abc(){super();}

    static void show(){
         System.out.println("Hey I am static");
    }
}
```

Hence by doing `new Abc().show();` you're just creating a new Abc object of your class and call the static method of the ABC class throught this object (it will show a warning because this is not the proper way to call static method).`

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use static methods from an instance, as in `new Abc().show()`, but it's potentially confusing and not recommended.

Stick to `className.staticMethod()` for static methods and `classInstance.instanceMethod()` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It simple means that you are creating object to ABC and than trying to accessing this variable through object.

However, at the time of compilation,

```
new Abc().show();
```

is converted to `Abc.show().`

Comment: Do you have any references for this ?

Comment: I use javap command with -c option. This is the output of the command  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
   Code:
      0: invokestatic  #2                  // Method Hi.sayHi:()V
      3: new           #3                  // class Hi
      6: dup
      7: invokespecial #4                  // Method Hi."<init>":()V
     10: astore_1
     11: aload_1
     12: pop
     13: invokestatic  #2                  // Method Hi.sayHi:()V
     16: return

public static void main(String a[]){
 
 Hi.sayHi();
 
 Hi hi = new Hi();
 
 hi.sayHi();
 
 }

Comment: I doubt that the compiler will strip this away. There is maybe code in the constructor (I know, bad practice), even static code ...

Answer (score 0):

Static keyword suggests only one copy per class now you have created method static and you are accessing using Classname.methodname() that is appropriate way because when class is loaded into JVM its instance will be created so no need to exlicitly create new Object of the class. hope it make sense.